# Visual C++ - UTF-8 - CA2W followed by CW2T with MBCS - Possibly a bad idea?

Tags: c++, utf-8, mbcs

I'm using a library that produces UTF-8 null-terminated strings in the `const char*` type. Examples include:

```
MIGUEL ANTÃ“NIO
DONA ESTEFÃ‚NIA
```

I'd like to convert those two `const char*` types to `CString` so that they read:

```
MIGUEL ANTÓNIO
DONA ESTEFÂNIA
```

To that effect, I'm using the following function I made:

```
CString Utf8StringToCString(const char * s)
{
    CStringW ws = CA2W(s, CP_UTF8);
    return CW2T(ws);
}
```

The function seems to do what I want (at least for those 2 cases). However, I'm wondering: is it a good idea at all to use the CA2W macro, followed by CW2T? Am I doing some sort of lossy conversion by doing this? Are there any side-effects I should worry about?

Some other details:

1. I'm using Visual Studio 2015
2. My application is compiled using **Use Multi-Byte Character Set**

Comment: CW2T will lose any Unicode characters that can't be represented with your code page.

Comment: Why are your project settings still on MBCS?  Do you still have customers on Windows 98?

Comment: @selbie Um... Honestly, I don't know. All of our customers use Windows 8, but I believe this is a legacy application. From what I understand, changing the setting to Unicode might break existing code...

Comment: @MiguelLopesMartins - I figured as much.  It's easy to work around though.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your application is compiled as MBCS, you can still use Unicode strings, buffers, and Windows Unicode APIs without any issue.

Pass your strings around as UTF-8 either with a raw pointer (`const char*`) or in a string class such as `CString` or `std::string`.  When you actually need to **render** the string for display, convert to Unicode and use the `W` API explicitly.

For example:

```
void UpdateDisplayText(const char* s)
{
    CStringW ws = CA2W(s, CP_UTF8);
    SetDlgItemTextW(m_hWnd, IDC_LABEL1, ws);
}
```